# How can I remove a stuck ethernet cable?

Tags: technology

So, I was helping someone with their router, and needed to access it via ethernet connection. I got the connection up and going, but now the cable is jammed and I can't get it out of my laptop.

I have tried holding the plastic tab down and pulling, but it's stuck in there, and I don't want to keep pulling because I'm pretty sure that's going to end in either damage to the cord, to my laptop, or both.

How can I get this cord out without dismantling my laptop?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/340131/how-to-unplug-a-network-cable-thats-stuck

Answer (score 13):

Dismantling the laptop would not work. Just get a small flat head screwdriver (the kind you'd use for spectacles) and pop it in along the plastic tab. It will push it further down than you may be able to do with your finger, and you should be able to pull the cable straight out.

Careful you only touch the screwdriver to the Ethernet port shield.

Comment: I've had the misfortune of having many stuck RJ45 heads in my experience and I'll say the flathead always works.